# Can't set jQuery dialog to width < 150px

Tags: jquery, dialog, width, jquery-ui-dialog

I cannot seem to set the width on a jQuery dialog to less than 150px. In other words, if I set it to something less, it will still display it at 150px.

The dialog call:

$('#menu').dialog({modal:false, height:window.innerHeight-20, width:125,dialogClass: "no-close", position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window }});

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            var menuOpen=false;
            function toggleFunctionMenu()
            {
                if(!menuOpen)
                {
                    $('#menu').dialog({modal:false, height:window.innerHeight-30, width:125,dialogClass: "no-close", position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window }});
                    $('#menuButton').html("Close");
                    menuOpen=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#menu').dialog("close");
                    $('#menuButton').html("Open");
                    menuOpen=false;
                }
            }


        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #menu
            {
                display: none;
                background-color: yellow;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                border-style:solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color:black;
                
            }

              #menuButton
              {
                  float:right;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="toggleFunctionMenu()" id="menuButton">Open</button>
        <div id="menu">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You noticed that your other CSS is not working either right? the `height` property is `auto` instead of the calculated value.

Comment: that sounds like a bug in jQuery UI, because even the documentation doesn't use quotes => http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width

Comment: PlantThelda actually the height is working. Try changing it to some value (like 200).

Comment: not in ur code snippet it doesnt ... inspection of the element shows it set to `height:auto` for the dialog.

Comment: Oh.. huh. You're right it does "say" auto- but still shows as what I set it to. Strange.

Interesting about that documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
         <style type="text/css">
            #menu
            {
                display: none;
                background-color: yellow;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                border-style:solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color:black;

            }

              #menuButton
              {
                  float:right;
              }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            var menuOpen=false;
            function toggleFunctionMenu()
            {
                if(!menuOpen)
                {
                    $('#menu').dialog({modal:false, height:window.innerHeight-30, width:'25px',dialogClass: "no-close", position: { my: "right bottom", at: "right bottom", of: window }});
                    $('#menuButton').html("Close");
                    menuOpen=true;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#menu').dialog("close");
                    $('#menuButton').html("Open");
                    menuOpen=false;
                }
            }


        </script>
        </head>
           <body>
        <button onclick="toggleFunctionMenu()" id="menuButton">Open</button>
        <div id="menu">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Logic works. Strange behavior though. If you put just 200 in, it makes it 200.

Comment: u have to change the order of css too :)

Comment: i was about to post pic too how output looks like

Comment: What do you mean by order of css?

Comment: place style tag first and then scripts follows as shown in my code

Comment: I have to say, forcing quotes here is a pain, because I actually grab the size from the internal element using something like this:

var w = $('#menu').width();
$('#menu').dialog({modal:false, height:window.innerHeight-30, width: w}}); 

In my real code the width of the div is set in css. So this means I have to turn the number into to a string?

Comment: And one more strange thing.. using a string ("500px") for height doesn't work.

Comment: #menu {
display: none;
background-color: #FF0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%!important;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #000;
}